# Fullscreen Background Image - Remove Black Space?

Tags: css, html

I have an image that I am using as a background in case the video background does not work. It is responsive and is working the way it's supposed to, but the image has black space at the top and bottom of the image. See: https://robotplaytime.paperplane.io/

Resizing the screens width smaller and the black space becomes more prominent.

Any idea how to remove the black space? The aspect ratio needs to be kept. The image can be larger than the screen size.

Thanks

HTML

```
<body>
    <video poster="images/robotPlaytimeVideo.png" id="bgvid">
    </video>
</body>
```

CSS

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: url(../images/robotPlaytimeVideo.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Next time use an image that has 20MB!! Will load much slower!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. The other example asks how to cover the screen and not have it repeat. The problem I have is that there is black space that appears even  after I try to cover. I still want to keep the aspect ratio and don't mind if it overflows.

Comment: Please share some code within your Question. External links are not tollerated on this site.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the description

Comment: Ok, now go open an image editor and remove the black portions out of your image. And while you're at your editor, make your image smaller. There's no other answer to your exact question as far as I can see.

Comment: There are no black portions in the actual image file, but making the image smaller will probably do it. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in css.

Comment: You clearly don't know what you're doing. Here's the link to your own image. https://robotplaytime.paperplane.io/images/robotPlaytimeVideo.png and as you can see it has black portions. What you're expecting is to automagically get rid of portions of an image? C'mon. Remove the dark lines, make your image smaller.

Comment: Oh man, that's totally my bad. Thanks

Comment: No problem. So, remove the blacks and do like you do it or see the duplicate answer. Happy coding.